# My player moves back after I stop any user input in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

In the first scene(grass scene), the player works fine in the grass scene, but inside the house, the player after any input the player moves back a bit.

https://i.imgur.com/aHXwCR7.mp4

My player movement script is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class playeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public Animator animator;
 
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;
    Vector2 movement;
    public static playeMovement instance;
    public string areaTransitionName;
 
    public void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
 
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
 
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
 
    public void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
 
        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
 
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Here is my follow camera script:

```
{
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothSpeed = 10f;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void Start()
    {
        //use for moving player to new scene
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;

        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you have some type of camera follow script, or camera parented to the player. For the sake of minimizing the variables to consider, can you record a fresh video where the camera is stationary in world space? This will help us observe the movement of the player a bit more clearly.

Comment: You might be on to something it doesn't do it with a different camera, i have added my follow camera script.

Comment: It could be your player isn't actually backing up, but the camera is catching up to them, so they seem to rubber-band back to the center of the screen.